# Making a horizontal list using ng-repeat? Not sure what I'm missing here

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Pretty simple question, but I've been staring at this code for way too long that I've become code blind and can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm simply trying to make a horizontal list of 2 image thumbnails within a modal using Angular's ng-repeat. Here is the HTML for it:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form name="socreForm">
                <div ng-hide="hasScreenshot === true"></div>
                <h3>Screenshots</h3>
                    <ul class = "imgList">
                        <li ng-repeat="item in screenshots">
                            <div style="text-align: center;">User: {{item.user}}</div>
                            <img class="thumbnail" ng-src = "{{item.imageURL}}">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <h3>Outcome</h3>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.outcome" name="outcome" ng-value="'1'">
                    <label>Win</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.outcome" name="outcome" ng-value="'2'">
                    <label>Lose</label>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS I'm trying to use:

```
.imgList {
  li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 40%
}
```

I've been fiddling with this for a while now and I simply cannot make it appear horizontally. This is what it looks like when it renders: [image: page render]

What silly CSS thing am I missing? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you using less/sass? If no the CSS you posted is not valid, try `.imgList li` as a selector (without the inner parenthesis `{}`).

Comment: Oh, yeah, should have mentioned that in my post. We are using .less.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<div style="text-align: center;">User: {{item.user}}</div>` with `<span style="text-align: center;">User: {{item.user}}</span>`

or add CSS rule like:

```
.imgList div {
  display: inline; //or inline-block
}
```

Divs are `display: block` by default (user agent stylesheet)